# Additional white space to List View Column headers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this very annoying issue with my multi-column List View. When I expand or shrink a column's width during application runtime, it adds up unwanted extra white space to both ends.  I want to get rid of this white space.

[image: ListView Control screenshot]

**XAML**

```
    <ListView Name="listUniversityRecordViewer">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Student Name" Width="120" Click="StudentNameColumn_Click"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Age" Width="120" Click="StudentAgeColumn_Click"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StudentAge}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Admission Date" Width="120" Click="StudentAdmDateColumn_Click"/>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdmissionDt}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

I tried using `GridViewColumn Header="StudentName" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StudentName}"` instead. It worked but removed my ability to implement `Click="StudentNameColumn_Click"` event which I need the most. Please help me get a balancing way to fix white space issue while retaining column click event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're setting `Width="120"` on your `GridViewColumnHeader`. Move the `Width` to your `GridViewColumn` and everything should work fine.

Also, there is no need to specify a `CellTemplate` if you're not doing anything custom. You can just use the `DisplayMemberBinding` property instead.

```
<GridViewColumn
    Width="120"
    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StudentName}">
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumnHeader
            Click="StudentNameColumn_Click"
            Content="Student Name" />
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
</GridViewColumn>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How do I add "Text Decorations" into it?